# What role do I assign to a user so he can manage MFA activities in my Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-rbac

I want to delegate the 'MFA activities' to a group of people, because it is very difficult for only one person (Global administrator) to do this job. However, I do not see any built-in role for delegating the MFA responsibilities using RBAC.

Can anyone help me with this or help me in creating a custom RBAC policy?

I have queried the roles using powershell, but I do not get anything useful.

```
$role_definition = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition | Format-Table Name, Description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [role of Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-manage-roles-portal) instead of the [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles). You can assign Authentication Administrator role(Allowed to view, set and reset authentication method information for any non-admin user.) to the users.

[image]